# How to convert general unit to SI unit

Tags: siunitx

Is it possible to automatically convert all used units in a document to one of the 7 SI units?

Where I for example have
`\unit{\pascal}`,

I would like to have it rendered as
`\unit{\newton\per\square\meter}`,
without needing to make the adjustments everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Isn't this task for editor? Just find and replace  `\unit{\pascal}` with `\unit{\newton\per\square\meter}` I wouldn't redefine existed unit.

Answer (score 6):

You could (re-)declare the units in question in your preamble once like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\pascal}{\newton\per\square\meter}

\begin{document}

\unit{\pascal}

\end{document}
```

Edit: In the [user manual](https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf), it says on page 14:

> The meaning of a pre-defined unit can be altered by using
> `\DeclareSIUnit` after loading siunitx. This will overwrite the
> original definition with the newer version.

So there shouldn't be any problems with using this approach.

Edit 2: I've taken the time to (re-)declare the SI derived units in the `siunitx` package where it made sense (see below, I used table 10 on [this site](https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/Siunitx.html) as reference and double-checked with Wikipedia). Note that I've added a `b` in front of the macro names, as to not overwrite the original macros. I've chosen to do so, because I came across one problem with declaring all derived units to be represented by the seven SI base units. There are abbreviations for units like `MPa` or `kN` defined in the package. Using those with abbreviations with redefined unit macros can lead not only to errors due to double prefixes but also wrong units, e.g. `Mm^{-1}kgs^{-2}` instead of `MPa`.
In conclusion, I'd avoid redefining the existing SI derived units, but use new ones instead. However, if you want to use the existing macros, be careful and don't use any abbreviations with prefixes (or at least check, which ones are safe) or overwrite them, too.

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\bhertz}{\per\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bnewton}{\kilo\gram\metre\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bpascal}{\kilo\gram\per\metre\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bjoule}{\kilo\gram\square\metre\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bwatt}{\kilo\gram\square\metre\per\cubic\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bcoulomb}{\ampere\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bvolt}{\kilo\gram\square\metre\per\ampere\per\cubic\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bfarad}{\per\kilo\gram\per\square\metre\square\ampere\second\tothe{4}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bohm}{\kilo\gram\square\metre\per\square\ampere\per\cubic\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bsiemens}{\per\kilo\gram\per\square\metre\square\ampere\cubic\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bweber}{\kilo\gram\square\metre\per\ampere\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\btesla}{\kilo\gram\per\ampere\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bhenry}{\kilo\gram\square\metre\per\square\ampere\per\square\second}
% wouldn't recommend using:
\DeclareSIUnit{\bbecquerel}{\per\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bgray}{\square\metre\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bsievert}{\square\metre\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bkatal}{\mole\per\second}
```

If you'd prefer the scheme/order of units `m-kg-s-A-K-mol-cd` the version below would be the way to go.

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\bhertz}{\per\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bnewton}{\metre\kilo\gram\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bpascal}{\per\metre\kilo\gram\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bjoule}{\square\metre\kilo\gram\per\square\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bwatt}{\square\metre\kilo\gram\per\cubic\second}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bcoulomb}{\second\ampere}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bvolt}{\square\metre\kilo\gram\per\cubic\second\per\ampere}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bfarad}{\per\square\metre\per\kilo\gram\second\tothe{4}\square\ampere}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bohm}{\square\metre\kilo\gram\per\cubic\second\per\square\ampere}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bsiemens}{\per\square\metre\per\kilo\gram\cubic\second\square\ampere}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bweber}{\square\metre\kilo\gram\per\square\second\per\ampere}
\DeclareSIUnit{\btesla}{\kilo\gram\per\square\second\per\ampere}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bhenry}{\square\metre\kilo\gram\per\square\second\per\square\ampere}
```

I left out `\radian` and `\steradian` since their SI base unit is `1` and also `\lumen` and `\lux` which are derived from `\candela` using `\steradian` which (I think) could lead to transformation errors (but I'm not completely sure about that, if you know better, feel free to let me know).
Also, since `\degreeCelsius` is only a derived unit relative to `273.15 K`, a direct transformation would lead to false quantities with absolute temperatures, so I didn't include it either.

Comment: The \pascal to \newton\per\square meter was an example, but it should actually be done for many different units, so I'm looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: Since the derived si unit macros (like all the unit macros) are implemented so that they represent a symbol (or a composition of symbols), there is no information about how the units are derived, that you could access, and use to change the units into different representations. As there are only 22 derived si units with special names (in the siunitx package), declaring their desired representation once seems to be the most efficient solution to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks! 22 seems indeed feasible to me.

Comment: However, there are some units, where you need to be careful (see my second edit).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\pascal}{\newton\per\square\meter}

\begin{document}

This is the distillation column pressure \SI{10}{\unit{\pascal}}.

\end{document}
```

Note: I am not sure if this breaks anything as `\pascal` is already defined, maybe someone will have a more appropriate answer but this appears to work with no obvious errors.

Comment: The \pascal to \newton\per\square meter was an example, but it should actually be done for many different units, so I'm looking for a more efficient solution, without having to look them up.

Comment: Just use `\DeclareSIUnit{}{}` for each of the units you want to change. I think what you are seeking is impossible, how could you redefine units without knowing which units to change in the first place?